# JSON decode resulting in Syntax Error

Tags: php, json

I'm using CURL function for a API call, and i'm not able to decode the json which i get in return.

when i checked with json_last_error() it says  "Syntax error, malformed JSON".

But i'm not sure what is the  syntax error in it.

I've tried using the below functions from exploring in internet, but the issue is not solved.

1. htmlentities((string)$result);
2. trim($result);

The result i'm getting in return as follows :

```
{"transactionResponse":{"responseCode":"3","authCode":"","avsResultCode":"P","cvvResultCode":"","cavvResultCode":"","transId":"0","refTransID":"","transHash":"AA22864D4298A9C13B16CA5C4B00087F","testRequest":"0","accountNumber":"XXXX0015","accountType":"MasterCard","errors":[{"errorCode":"11","errorText":"A duplicate transaction has been submitted."}],"transHashSha2":""},"refId":"9898989898","messages":{"resultCode":"Error","message":[{"code":"E00027","text":"The transaction was unsuccessful."}]}}
```

Kindly help me with this issue.

Many thanks.

Comment: If above is your json response then i am able to decode it with `json_decode` function successfully. Is there anything else which you are missing to mention here...

Comment: Yes, i just checked by copying the response i pasted it here.
but when i directly try to decode the result i'm getting the syntax error.

Comment: I've updated my entire code in another post. please visit here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40459163/json-decode-results-in-syntax-error-when-directly-decoding-the-response-from-cur